# Access single cell of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following data with some missing holes. I've looked over the 'how to handle missing data' but can't find anything that applies in this situation. Here is the data:

```
          Species GearUsed  AverageFishWeight(lbs) NormalRange(lbs)  Caught  
0   BlackBullhead  Gillnet                    0.11          0.8-7.7    0.18   
1    BlackCrappie  Trapnet                    6.22          0.7-3.4    0.30   
2             NaN  Gillnet                    1.00          0.6-3.5    0.30   
3        Bluegill  Trapnet                   11.56         6.1-46.6    0.14   
4             NaN  Gillnet                    1.44              NaN    0.21   
5   BrownBullhead  Trapnet                    0.11          0.4-2.1    1.01   
6    NorthernPike  Trapnet                    0.22              NaN    4.32   
7             NaN  Gillnet                    2.22         3.5-10.5    5.63   
8     Pumpkinseed  Trapnet                    0.89          2.0-8.5    0.23   
9        RockBass  Trapnet                    0.22          0.5-1.8    0.04   
10        Walleye  Trapnet                    0.22          0.3-0.7    0.28   
11            NaN  Gillnet                    1.56          1.3-5.0    2.54   
12    WhiteSucker  Trapnet                    0.33          0.3-1.4    2.76   
13            NaN  Gillnet                    1.78          0.5-2.7    1.32   
14    YellowPerch  Trapnet                    1.33          0.5-3.3    0.14   
15            NaN  Gillnet                   27.67         3.4-43.6    0.14
```

I need the NaNs in the species column to just be the name above it, for example row 2 would be BlackCrappie. I would like to iterate through the frame and manually specify the species name but am not too sure of how, and also other answers recommend against iterating through the dataframe in the first place.

How do I access each cell of the frame individually? Thanks!

PS the column names are incorrect, there is not a 27lb yellow perch. :)

Comment: To reiterate what the other answers were probably getting at: do you actually need to iterate through the frame, or do you simply *think* you need to iterate through the frame in order to fix the NaNs?  Because there's no need here.

Comment: I do need to fix the NaNs because this will be stored in a sql database, if thats what you mean, otherwise no I don't see how pandas or numpy can correct this. I'm new to dataframes though. Thanks DSM.

Comment: The point is that with `pandas` you want to do as much as possible using fast built-in operations rather than going element by element.  In this case, using `fillna`, as CT Zhu has demonstrated (and you can select specific columns, or change the fill algorithm.)

Comment: DSM is spot on, also, consider `df['Species']=df.Species.fillna(method='pad')` if you just want to do the filling for the species name row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to fill the missing values in other rows as well? Seems to be what `fillna()` is for:

```
In [83]:

print df.fillna(method='pad')
          Species GearUsed  AverageFishWeight(lbs) NormalRange(lbs)  Caught
0   BlackBullhead  Gillnet                    0.11          0.8-7.7    0.18
1    BlackCrappie  Trapnet                    6.22          0.7-3.4    0.30
2    BlackCrappie  Gillnet                    1.00          0.6-3.5    0.30
3        Bluegill  Trapnet                   11.56         6.1-46.6    0.14
4        Bluegill  Gillnet                    1.44         6.1-46.6    0.21
5   BrownBullhead  Trapnet                    0.11          0.4-2.1    1.01
6    NorthernPike  Trapnet                    0.22          0.4-2.1    4.32
7    NorthernPike  Gillnet                    2.22         3.5-10.5    5.63
8     Pumpkinseed  Trapnet                    0.89          2.0-8.5    0.23
9        RockBass  Trapnet                    0.22          0.5-1.8    0.04
10        Walleye  Trapnet                    0.22          0.3-0.7    0.28
11        Walleye  Gillnet                    1.56          1.3-5.0    2.54
12    WhiteSucker  Trapnet                    0.33          0.3-1.4    2.76
13    WhiteSucker  Gillnet                    1.78          0.5-2.7    1.32
14    YellowPerch  Trapnet                    1.33          0.5-3.3    0.14
15    YellowPerch  Gillnet                   27.67         3.4-43.6    0.14
```

Comment: No, just the species column, because padding the data values is not accurate. I think I've got it from here though, thanks! I'll mark in a few minutes.

Comment: Ha, just commented on that 4 secs ago in the OP.

Comment: Yea lots of quick responses! Can't even keep up! Thanks!